# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: >= near line 1

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, exception

i got an exception, when i run this query with Hibernate:

```
String query = "FROM A st, B g "
                + "WHERE st.name = g.name AND st.name LIKE :name AND "
                + "g.id = ANY (SELECT c FROM C "
                + "WHERE CASE WHEN name = 'test' THEN condiction >= :value end)";

        try {
            return (List) entityManager.createQuery(query)
                    .setParameter("name", "%" + name + "%")
                    .setParameter("value", value).getResultList();
        } catch (SecurityException | IllegalStateException | RollbackException e) {
            LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
```

i got an execption:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: >= near line 1, column 336 ...
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Any ideas about it? i use mysql a database. Can i use CASE WHEN THEN in hibernate? The same query work fine on the command line.

Thank
Cheers

Comment: It is hard to tell. Did you  try to partly run your SQL and see what is good and whats not?

Comment: when i run only WHERE name = 'test' AND condiction >= :value, i worked perfectly. But i need a WHEN CASE Clause. I think, it is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have the syntax of the `CASE` expression incorrect.  It should be like this (I think):

```
  WHERE CASE :name
    WHEN 'test' THEN condiction >= :value
    ELSE false
  END
```

... except that `condiction` doesn't make any sense here.

At any rate, the syntax for a `CASE` expression is given here in the Java EE 6 tutorial:

- [Full Query Language Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#gjjnd)

Comment: i try it, but i doesn't work. I got the same exception. WHERE CASE :name WHEN 'test' THEN condiction >= :value ELSE false end. Another ideas?

Comment: Like I said, the stuff with `condiction` makes no sense to me.  What is that all about?

Comment: i want to check different cases not only one. CASE :name WHEN 'test' THEN condiction >= :value WHEN 'test2' THEN condiction <= :value ELSE false end

Comment: But `condiction` is not valid HSQL

Comment: what about [Hibernate Case expressions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3280). Check 11.4.11. CASE expressions. And hier [16.10. Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)